# How to log script output to STDOUT and a file

Tags: ruby, mixlib-shellout

I have the following Ruby block:

```
ruby_block "Validate" do
  block do
    require "mixlib/shellout"
    begin
      cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("/usr/local/bin/someScript.py", :timeout => 3600)
      cmd.live_stream = STDOUT
      cmd.run_command
      cmd.error!
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Action failed..."
      return 168
    end
  end
  action :create
  notifies :create, "ruby_block[Validated]", :immediately
  not_if { node[:state][:validated] == true }
end
```

I want to log the result of the script into both STDOUT and a file called "/tmp/xml_diff_results.txt".

The first thing I did was change:

```
cmd=Mixlib::ShellOut.new("/usr/local/bin/someScript.py", :timeout => 3600)
```

to:

```
cmd=Mixlib::ShellOut.new("/usr/local/bin/someScript.py > /tmp/xml_diff_results.txt", :timeout => 3600)
```

however, that did not do what I expected.

Then I noticed the `cmd.live_stream` variable. Is there a way I can tap into that and do something like this?:

```
cmd.live_stream = (STDOUT > /tmp/xml_diff_results.txt)
```

**SOLUTION:**

The solution to my problem was simple and inspired by @tensibai.

```
log_file = File.open('/tmp/chef-run.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND)
LOG = Logger.new(log_file)

def shell(command)
  LOG.info "Execute: #{command}"
  cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(command, :timeout => 1800)
  cmd.run_command
  LOG.info "Returned: #{cmd.stdout}"
  cmd.error!
  cmd
end
```

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option in Ruby (just the inner part) in case `tee` is not available (windows):

```
  cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("/usr/local/bin/someScript.py", :timeout => 3600)
  cmd.live_stream = STDOUT
  cmd.run_command
  # new part
  log=::Tempfile.new(["xml_diff_results",".txt"])
  errlog=::File.open(log.path.gsub(".txt",".err")
  log.write(cmd.stdout)
  errlog.write(cmd.stderr)
  log.close
  errlog.close
  Chef::Log.info("Log results are in #{log.path}")
  # end of new part 
  cmd.error!
```

Change the `Chef::Log` level to `warn` if you run chef-client without `-l info` and really want the path to be printed in chef log.

Main advantage is that it's platform independent, drawback is that the log files will only be written once the command has ended its execution.

Comment: Actually this is more like what I'm looking for. I am going to test this now.

Comment: @Jakir00 I forgot to say it is untested code, I'll be happy if you can confirm this is ok (it should be as far as I know `shell_out`, but I may have missed a case)

Comment: Using this as psudo-code worked. I didn't copy/paste this but I ended up using this methodology to write the logs from the command output. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a Ruby or even Chef question. It's more like a Bash question

One way to run a command, and redirect its output to stdout and a file, could be using **[`tee`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html)**

```
echo 'Hello World!' | tee output.log
```

So, with your example it could be like this

```
cmd=Mixlib::ShellOut.new("/usr/local/bin/someScript.py | tee /tmp/xml_diff_results.txt", :timeout => 3600)
```

Comment: This just might work. I will give this a shot tomorrow when after my branch gets merged.